# How do I change the sort order of the left menu blocks in the admin backend?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminhtml, local.xml

I want to re-order the menu blocks so the ones that almost never used are far down the page. I have read numerous posts here and on other sites, however I do not see a single unified answer. The answers range from dealing with the local.xml file to adminhtml. The image below is the current sort order. I want to be able to control the location of each block.

[image: Current Sort Order]

Comment: Instead of .... try this https://github.com/Flagbit/Magento-ChangeAttributeSet/

Comment: Thank you sv3n, but that is not what I'm wishing to change.

Answer (score 0):

At each Magento Core module that has the menu, you will find in the `app/code/core/Mage/ModulName/etc/system.xml` how the order is created.

You have to make a simple module in `app/etc/Namespace/ModulName.xml` to specify the dependence of the modules you want to modify the menu order.

Example of ordering of Mage_Contacts (Path is: app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/etc/system.xml):

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <contacts translate="label" module="contacts">
            <label>Contacts</label>
            <tab>general</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <contacts translate="label">
                    <label>Contact Us</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enabled translate="label">
                            <label>Enable Contact Us</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <backend_model>contacts/system_config_backend_links</backend_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enabled>
                    </fields>
                </contacts>
                <email translate="label">
                    <label>Email Options</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <recipient_email translate="label">
                            <label>Send Emails To</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <validate>validate-email required-entry</validate>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </recipient_email>
                        <sender_email_identity translate="label">
                            <label>Email Sender</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_identity</source_model>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </sender_email_identity>
                        <email_template translate="label">
                            <label>Email Template</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </email_template>
                    </fields>
                </email>
            </groups>
        </contacts>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Comment: helped you with my answer?